# How to live-style an user input using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im searching for a libary or suggestions for making a real time styler in javascript/jquery. The idea is that my users have a html text input, i need to detect in real time some patterns and apply an style to it, for example is the user writes #some_text all after the # should be considered like a tag a have to be bold like **#some_text**.

Im very new at javascript so i have no idea of where to begin, i did some research but i didn't find any already made libary. Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Comment: Your example is not very clear. Can you show us some before/after snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like [jQuery Tagit](http://webspirited.com/tagit/)?

You could initialize it like this:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var availableTags = [
                "#some_text1",
                "#some_text2",
                "#some_text3"
            ];

            $('#tags').tagit({tagSource: availableTags});
        });
</script>

<ul id="tags"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that is used right here, on this website. Whenever you write a question or an answer in the editor, you get a live update in the area below. When you apply formatting it's updated in real-time in the preview area.

This uses a standard mark-up syntax called [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). What's good about that is that there are many tools that support Markdown, so you can find integrations for [jQuery](https://github.com/tstone/jquery-markedit) and even offline editors ([Windows](http://markdownpad.com/) and [Mac](http://mouapp.com/)).

[Check this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874646/which-stack-overflow-style-markdown-wmd-javascript-editor-should-i-use) for some editors that do this.

Also check out [the stand-alone version of the Stack Overflow editor](http://ephemera.continuation.org/stackoverflow/wmd/wmd-test.html).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps you a little bit to understand what you have to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/EeGxs/3/
  All I did is add an event listener to 'keydown' which means a key is pressed, and then you just have a look if there is a '#' in the line and if you add it to the p -tag which is bold.
Its only a demonstration.